# GROUP BY different column conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show a list of chat messages.

For this I have a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT id, `from`, sent, message, recd FROM chat 
WHERE id IN(
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat
  WHERE `to` = ? GROUP BY `from`
)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The problem is, I want to select messages that `to` = maria and `from` = maria conditionally.

That is, if `to` = maria I want to group by `from`, and if `from` = maria, I want to group by `to`.

How can I change this `GROUP BY` dynamically?

Comment: You want the latest message that is either `from` or `to` `'maria'`? Or both?

Comment: yeah! it is a messenger like whatsapp, viber... with this select above I cant get messages with no answers @ypercube

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Do you want only the 1 (or 2) latest messages (from and to) maria? Or all the latest messages (eg the latest message from george to maria, the latest from john to maria, the latest from maria to alice, the latest from alice to maria, etc)?

Comment: just 1, the latest message from john to maria. and order this messages to maria by id desc @ypercube

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Rick Joe: I am happy you've accepted my answer :-) However, you haven't really answered ypercube's question. Your answer is more or less "I want one record only, ordered by ID", which obviously makes no sense. My query gets the latest message per partner, no matter whether to or from. If this is what you are after, is it so hard to say so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the proposed queries are fine - meaning they will return the expected results (one row for every different user that has sent or received a message from `'maria'`) - but efficiency may not be great. MySQL does not optimize well queries with `WHERE column IN (complex subquery)`. The optimizer has some improvements in 5.6 and 5.7 version but still it's much better to help it in getting a better plan and using indexes.

Your question and comments are confusing though. it's not clear if you want one row per different user (recipient, sender) or just one row in the results.

If you want the second, my suggestion is to add two indexes, on `(to)` and `(from)` if you haven't already (I assume that the table is InnoDB and the primary key is `(id)` so the `(to)` and `(from)` indexes are equivalent to `(to, id)` and `(from, id)` indexes, which are what you really need for the query.)

and use the following query:

```
  ( SELECT id, `from`, `to`, sent, message, recd 
    FROM chat 
    WHERE `to` = ?
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
UNION ALL
  ( SELECT id, `from`, `to`, sent, message, recd 
    FROM chat 
    WHERE `from` = ?
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

which is equivalent (thank you @Thorsten Kettner) to:

```
SELECT id, `from`, `to`, sent, message, recd 
FROM chat 
WHERE ? IN (`to`, `from`) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Try this last version, too, and if it is equally efficient, prefer it. There is no reason to complicate the query, unless the efficiency is not good. With the given indexes, this last version will often use both of them, and the **[index merge union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-optimization.html)** algorithm.

Comment: oh, it is amazing! thank you! in fact I have:   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from` (`from`),
  KEY `to` (`to`) - isn't it good?

Comment: So *this* is what was wanted? :-) That's simply `SELECT * FROM chat WHERE ? IN (to, from) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`, only obfuscated. I think we shouldn't get too paranoid when writng SQL. Make your queries as simple and readable as possible and only change them when running into problems. The DBMS should be able to deal with such simple queries. And using an index is not always the fastest way to get to the data.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I agree that your query is 100% equivalent to mine. But I disagree on the indexes part. What other way is faster than using indexes?

Comment: A full table scan can be much faster when a person's messages make for a large percentage of the data. So I think it's good advice to have the indexes, but we shouldn't write our queries such as to kind of force their usage. Let the DBMS' optimizer decide how to go about it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes a full table scan is sometimes better (although technically, an InnoDB table is an index, not much different than a usual index) than an index scan or an index seek. But in this case, we are interested in only 1 (or few) rows, there is absolutely no need to scan the table.

Comment: The *result* is one row; the rows we must look at to get this one row can be thousands :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner exactly, that's why an index seek (or 2) is much, much better than a table or index scan.

Comment: But with every find in the index you also access the row to get the ID, which is your key to find the latest message. So let's say a person's message make for 90% of all messages :-( You would read the index, but access almost every row in the table, too. It would be much faster to simply read the table sequentially. Depending on the DBMS and data the threshold when best to use an index can be as low as 5%. However, in general you are right; most often an index use is faster, and it is good to provide indexes. Here, compound indexes could be great too: (to,id) + (from,id) or (to,from,id).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm not sure if you are talking about my query or in general. My query has `LIMIT 1` in both subqueries so it will only do 2 index seeks (one for each subquery), assuming that it does finds proper indexes and uses them. It will only then go the table and read the relevant 2 rows (and then do the UNION and the last LIMIT 1, which would be fast since there would be only 2 rows).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91470/discussion-between-ypercube-and-thorsten-kettner).

Answer (score 2):

I would got for a UNION.

```
(SELECT id, 'from' as direction, m_from AS fromto, sent, message, recd
FROM chat WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat WHERE to = 'Maria' GROUP BY m_from))
UNION
(SELECT id, 'to' as direction, m_to AS fromto, sent, message, recd FROM chat
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat WHERE m_from = 'Maria' GROUP BY to))
```

If you select MAX(id) an ORDER BY id statement is not necessary.

You can add extra fields in the SELECT clause as I did with 'direction'.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CASE construct for conditional grouping:

```
SELECT id, `from`, sent, message, recd 
FROM chat 
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat
  WHERE 'Maria' in (`to`, `from`)
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN 'Maria' = `to` THEN `from` ELSE `to` END
)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` within the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT id, `from`, sent, message, recd 
FROM chat 
WHERE id IN(SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM chat
            WHERE `to` = ? OR `from` = ?
            GROUP BY CASE 
                     WHEN `to` = ? THEN  GROUP BY `from`
                     ELSE `from` = ? THEN  GROUP BY `to`
                     END)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: You cannot have `THEN GROUP BY` inside a `CASE` expression.